# Retrieving oauth access token without client_secret

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have been following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) on using oauth. I have done up to step 4 and have generated a code successfully. I am now looking at step five and am stuck.

I want to get the access token to access the gcloud storage json api. The program is a extension for vscode, it runs in a node js environment on the users machine.

The problem is that it asks for the client secret. I cannot restrict it due to where it is running, so will I have to expose the secret? It also asks for the redirect url specified in the api console but mine is blank as I used the `Loopback IP address`. Do I use the loopback ip or should I set it to null? Also it asks for the `code_verifier` but I have not generated one as step 3 says this is "recommended" but not a necessity???

How can I get the access token with being in this enviroment?

Comment: You are using the wrong type of OAuth. You probably want to use this one: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent However, the answer depends on information is not in your question. If the user logging in owns the Cloud Storage Bucket, good. Otherwise, you will need to implement server side OAuth and Client ID/Client Secret will be required at the server (not at the client). This also means a registered domain name, etc.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hmm, but for this method it does not have a refresh token. Does that mean the user had to go through the auth screen each time they need the need the access token? (verified they have not generated one in the last hour)

Comment: If you want a Refresh Token, you will need to implement server-side OAuth, otherwise, the client will need to authenticate again when the Access Token expires.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't understand. Like mentioned in the question I am building a vscode extension where the auth flow will run on the users local machine. Are you suggesting I build a server instance to interact as middleware between the application and their bucket? Surely there is a better way than that???

Comment: The Client Secret is a secret. There is no other way to protect it than to build a server-side application so the user does not see it. I recommend that you study how OAuth works and the various "Flows" that implement security. Google is very restrictive in which parts of OAuth that you can implement.

Comment: It _is_ possible to use the code flow with refresh tokens even from a client side application, in this case one can leave out the client secret or pass an empty string if the parameter is required. Usually the client side app registers a custom url scheme which is passed as redirect url, how this works for a vscode extension I do not know.